# Command filtering

Tags: c++, parsing, command, bots, irc

Currently writing an IRC bot for fun and I have some trouble setting up the bot to listen to my commands. ( Works for !quit but not for !join or !leave )

```
void onPrivMsg(IRCMessage message, IRCClient* client)
{
    // received text
    std::string text = message.parameters.at(message.parameters.size() - 1);

    if (text[0] == '!')
    {
    if (text == "!Join #channel" || text == "!join #channel")
        client->SendIRC("JOIN #channel");
    if (text == "!Leave #channel" || text == "!leave #channel")
        client->SendIRC("PART #channel");
    if (text == "!Quit" || text == "!quit")
        client->SendIRC("QUIT");
    } else{
        client->SendIRC("PRIVMSG #channel :Wrong command.");
    }
}
```

I'm calling it like so:

```
client.HookIRCCommand("PRIVMSG", &onPrivMsg);
```

How would I get the channel name (#ChannelISpecify) from the text message line?

Example: If I'd type "!join #funnyposts" in IRC it would join the channel #funnyposts.
Appriciate any kind of help.

Comment: This is not a very specific question. You're asking how to create a syntax and the associated parser?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm trying to make the bot listen to the commands i type via mIRC or an online client. I don't know how to make it so it joins that channel that I type in. It'll only join the channel I specify in the code and I don't want that.

Comment: So the answer to my question is "yes"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In a way yes I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Now filters for different commands and acts accordingly.

```
if (text[0] == '!')
{
    std::string commandApi = text.substr(0, text.find(" "));
    if (commandApi == "!Join" || commandApi == "!join"){
        if (commandApi[0] = '!'){
            commandApi[0] = '/';
        }
        std::string channel2 = text.substr(text.find("#"));
        client->SendIRC("PRIVMSG " + channel2 + " :Joining channel");
        client->SendIRC("JOIN " + channel2);
    }
```